# Input field with two value

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have two input fields as this:

1. `input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">`
2. `input type="hidden" name="action" value="admin_login">`

I have two separate login forms, which I want to become one

I've searched for the solution on internet and it seems that it is better to let in tho form the value of "login", so that normal users login using their credentials, and then do some javascript in the page translated as IF `username === adminX` then this. form `value="admin_login"`.

Any help on how to accomplish this, I don't know much of javascript

Comment: The problem is that this approach is incredibly insecure. There is nothing preventing me from altering the HTML in my browser and changing your hidden value to whatever I want (example: I'm a regular user and want to login as admin, I can change it to `admin_login`, and away we go). To prevent me from doing that, I would hope you have some server-side validation that would determine whether the user is an admin. And if that is the case, ultimately I don't forsee you needing either of those hidden fields at all.

Comment: @Teeg: i have build the site, and then try to make an unic login form (previously are two separately), from where the client enter in his invoice system, where everything is server side (php and mysql), so nothing insecure about that. the only thing insecure is that the username in in html plain text :).

Comment: @Leon so what do those hidden fields actually do (meaning why do you need them in the HTML)?

Comment: @Teeg: now that you ask me :), i know that they were on the original form, and the value they have(login or admin_login), is like a redirect to admin panel or client panel ... now i ask myself if i put the value="login" somewhere else in the form, and delete the hidden fild if they work :), any suggestions? thank you

Comment: updated the bottom version.. seem that the hidden field is not needed, thank you for the head's up Teeg. If somehow you have something else to add, feel free, i'm opened to suggestions :)

Comment: @Leon Nope, I have no more suggestions. If you removed the hidden field, then you're good. Just remember, you always want to keep away from the browser any information that relates to authentication. For example: let your server-side php code (or whatever you're ultimately using) figure out where it should redirect to based on who the user actually is (according to the database), not where the browser tells it to redirect to (which is dangerous of course); stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using java script you can do this by

```
<script>
function check_login() {
if (userType==admin){
 Myform.value="admin_login";}
else{
 Myform.value="user";
}
}
</script>
<input type="submit" onclick="check_login()">
```

I think the best way to do this by having single form for both user but now depend on server side how you handle it.like

```
if(userType==admin_login) {
//show admin permissions for result page
}
else{
hide all admin permissions and show only given permission for normal user for result page
}
```

Comment: in the mentime i've done succesfuly with  <input type="hidden" name="action" id="log" value="login">     and javascript <script type="text/javascript">
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value = 'admin';

    function setVal(){
      if( username === 'admin') {
        document.getElementById("log").value = 'admin_login';
      }
    }
  </script>

Answer (score 0):

later: done it like this, because next day the version from comment is not working anymore..boh

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" onBlur="myFunction()" name="username" value="">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
<button type="submit" name="action" id="log" value="login">SIGN UP</button>
</form>
```

and javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(){
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    if(username == 'admin'){
    document.getElementById("log").value='admin_login';
    }else{
    document.getElementById("log").value='login';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Hope it helps someone in the future. Thank you!